# How to set up an eclipse update site and force one optional package?

Tags: eclipse, p2

I developed several plug-ins for eclipse that are bundled in one update site. Until now.
Now I have added an extension point to one of the plug-ins and implemented two plug-ins that can hook up to that extension point. I want to set up the update site such that a user is forced to install my package with one and only one of the extension plug-ins. Can I do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: What happens if you just make the project with the extension point dependent on the extension plug-in?

Comment: Both do. But this does not stop anyone to install both extension point projects.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way to create a feature to contains both the plug-in provided the extension point and the plug-in implemented the extension. Then export the feature to a repository.

Comment: This would mean I have to set up two update sites. I would like to have only one.